# Regex: How could I avoid a character class?

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to write this without the `[^...]` but with using the `\P{...}`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use utf8;

my $string = '_${Hello}?${World}!';

$string =~ s/[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}]/-/g; 

say "<$string>";
```

Comment: @anubhava, just run the program.  It's `<_--Hello----World-->`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's *possible* but I don't think I'd call it an improvement:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use utf8;

my $string = '_${Hello}?${World}!';

$string =~ s/(?=\P{Alphabetic})
             (?=\P{Mark})
             (?=\P{Decimal_Number})
             (?=\P{Connector_Punctuation}) . /-/xgs;

say "<$string>";
```

With multiple positive lookaheads, they all have to succeed.  So it matches one character (the `.`) that is not Alphabetic and not Mark and not Decimal_Number and not Connector_Punctuation, just like the negated character class would.

I added the `/s` modifier because the original regex would match a newline (although your sample string doesn't have one).  I added `/x` so I could add some whitespace and break it over multiple lines.

What do you have against character classes, anyway?

Comment: it seems, that author like obvios perl, without `[^\]\[\{]+?`. good technique and readable code :)

Comment: On the way of trying to remember something that I've read somewhere this question crossed my path.